# NSWindow loses miniaturize button on Lion

Tags: objective-c, osx-lion, nswindow, minimize, titlebar

I'm having this problem on OSX Lion when entering/exiting fullscreen. I tried to reapply the style mask without success:

```
NSUInteger styleMask = NSResizableWindowMask | NSClosableWindowMask |  NSMiniaturizableWindowMask | NSTitledWindowMask;
styleMask |= NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask;

window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:windowFrame 
                                      styleMask: styleMask
                                        backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered 
                                          defer:NO];
```

and the fullscreen notification

```
(void)didExitFull:(NSNotification *)notification {
   NSUInteger styleMask=[window styleMask];
   [window setStyleMask:styleMask|NSMiniaturizableWindowMask];

}
```

It seems that the miniaturize button is not getting enable again.
I also found this UI Usability problems on MacOSX 10.6 [here](http://openradar.appspot.com/7404099)

Comment: I went further and realized that for some reason the miniaturize button was just in disabled state. So adding `code`[[window standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton] setEnabled:YES]; `code` will activate the button again. The problem is that this happens only when the window updates itself gaining focus from back to frontmost.

Answer (score 2):

Please override the following function

```
- (NSApplicationPresentationOptions) window:(NSWindow *)window willUseFullScreenPresentationOptions:(NSApplicationPresentationOptions)proposedOptions
{
    return (proposedOptions| NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideToolbar);
}
```

And do not set styleMask after exitFullscreen. Let the system do it.